# Want to create a UIContoller in a UITabController but with no tab button

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I want to display an intro view (tutorial) on my monotouch app that when the user clicks on a button will take them to the main storyboard, which contains a UITabController. 
I'm new to monotouch and can't work out how to do this. I'm adding an extra view that's been created to the tab bar controller in the AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching, but this always adds the button to the tab bar.

When the user has clicked the button once I don't want to show the intro page ever again, it's a one time deal (I'll save some value to disk to work this out), so I don't want to just add it to the tab controller.

Incidentally if anyone can show me where monotouch decides that it's going to start with the storyboard please let me know. The only thing I've found is the little start arrow that you drag around in XCode, but what if I have two storyboards and I want to load one based on the user being logged in or something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create simple entry ViewController with the button (Controller1). The next controller in storyboard will be the tabcontroller (TabController).

Thus you will always has the first entry screen in your application.

If you don't want to show it later than make transition from Controller1 to TabController before it is loaded. For example, override the ViewWillAppear method.

The second approach. Use this code to launch whatever you want view above all your controllers at any time:

```
UIViewController root= UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController
UIView myCustomView=new MyCustomView();
root.Add(myCustomView);
//call myCustomView.RemoveFromSuperview() and it will be dismissed
```